# Binomial product expansion

Tags: binomial-theorem

I have seen the following mathematical identity in a book:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^{N}\left( 1 + ax_i \right)^c = \left( 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{N}{ax_i} + \cdots + a^N\prod_{i=1}^{N}{x_i}  \right)^c
$$

Is this a generalization of the Binomial theorem? What are the implicit terms within $\cdots$? Any explanations, proofs, references are appreciated!

Comment: Should that $a^N$ be on the outside of the product?  For $c=1$ and $x_i=1$ you have (1+a)^N = 1 + \cdots + a^(N^2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows from the "Multi-Binomial Theorem".  Quoted from the wiki page for the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

$$(x_{1}+y_{1})^{n_{1}}\dotsm(x_{d}+y_{d})^{n_{d}} = \sum_{k_{1}=0}^{n_{1}}\dotsm\sum_{k_{d}=0}^{n_{d}} \binom{n_{1}}{k_{1}}\, x_{1}^{k_{1}}y_{1}^{n_{1}-k_{1}}\;\dotsc\;\binom{n_{d}}{k_{d}}\, x_{d}^{k_{d}}y_{d}^{n_{d}-k_{d}}$$

Answer (score 1):

These are simply [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas), expressing the relations between roots and coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a generalisation of the Binomial theorem because the exponent of $c$ isn't really handled -- they just took it outside. If you were to expand out the right-hand-side, you would have a generalisation of the Binomial theorem.