# converting binomial product to a sum

Tags: summation, binomial-theorem, products

sorry if this was already posted, consider the product involving $n$ variables $X_i$,
$$
P=\prod_{i=1}^n X_i^{k_i}(1-X_i)^{1-k_i},
$$
where $k_i$ ($i=1,...,n$) assumes either 0 or 1. Thinking of all the combinations of $(k_1,\cdots,k_n)$ of $n$ binary terms, can we convert the product above in a summation for any sequence of binary terms? I mean, without log-transformation.

My try:
$$
X_1^{k_1}(1-X_1)^{1-k_1}\times X_2^{k_2}(1-X_2)^{1-k_2}\times \cdots\times X_n^{k_n}(1-X_n)^{1-k_n},
$$
for the sequence ($0,\cdots,0$)
$$
(1-X_1)\times (1-X_2)\times \cdots\times (1-X_n),
$$
which may be expressed through multi-binomial theorem, such as in [Binomial product expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331401/binomial-product-expansion/1331416#1331416) (I would like to have something similar)

However, as the complexity of the combinations increases (that is, many 1's and 0's), I find a bit difficult to find a general expression. I'd appreciate any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about $(\prod_{k_i=1}X_i)(\prod_{k_i=0}(1-X_i))$?

Answer (score 1):

Hye,

Denoting $I_0=\{i\mid k_i=0\}$ and $I_1=\{i\mid k_i=1\}$, you can develop your polynomial as follows:

$$\left(\prod_{i\in I_1}X_i\right)\left(\prod_{i\in I_0}(1-X_i)\right)=\left(\prod_{i\in I_1}X_i\right)\left(\sum_{I\subset I_0}(-1)^{|I|}\prod_{i\in I}X_i\right)=(-1)^{|I_1|}\sum_{I\mid I_1\subset I}(-1)^{|I|}\prod_{i\in I}X_i.$$

I hope this can help.

Comment: thanks, what $|.|$ stands for?

Comment: $|I|$ is the number of elements in the set (of indices) $I$

Comment: Hi Le, it seems an application of the multi-binomial theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Multi-binomial_theorem), but I am bit confused with the indexes:

(1) the expression in the center, the second product shouldnt be $i\in I_0$?

(2) the RHS, the indexes of the summation shouldnt have a constraint to avoiding multiplying repeated terms? I didn't understand "$I|I_1\subset I$", shouldn't be something like $1\leq i_1<\cdots<i_n\leq n$?

Comment: An exemple:
$$\prod_{i\in\{1,2\}}(1-X_i)=\underbrace{1}_{I=\emptyset}-\underbrace{X_1}_{I=\{1\}}-\underbrace{X_2}_{I=\{2\}}+\underbrace{X_1X_2}_{I=\{1,2\}}$$
Another:
$$\prod_{i\in\{1,2,3\}}(1-X_i)=\underbrace{1}_{I=\emptyset}-\underbrace{X_1}_{I=\{1\}}-\underbrace{X_2}_{I=\{2\}}-\underbrace{X_3}_{I=\{3\}}+\underbrace{X_1X_2}_{I=\{1,2\}}+\underbrace{X_1X_3}_{I=\{1,3\}}+\underbrace{X_2X_3}_{I=\{2,3\}}-\underbrace{X_1X_2X_3}_{I=\{1,2,3\}}.$$